# EF 7 .Include doesn't retrieve child's recored of parent

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I use EF7 RC1 and have this code but only child's of first parent record retrieve:

```
var res = await _labcontext.Customers
                    .Include(x => x.Invoives)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Title)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                   .Skip((page - 1) * pagesize).Take(pagesize)
                   .ToListAsync();
```

This is a bug in EF7 or my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams we should call pagination before include, I change my code as bellow and work fine.

```
var res = await _labcontext
                    .Customers.AsNoTracking()
                     .Skip((page - 1) * pagesize).Take(pagesize)
                    .Include(x => x.Invoives)
                      .OrderBy(x => x.Title)
```

Comment: your OrderBy should be before Skip.. otherwise the results will be unpredictable